# Getting exception in editing customer details from admin panel in magento 2

Tags: exception, migration, magento2

I am attaching the exception log and base URL below

URL:
https://dev.xxxxxxx.com/admin/customer/index/edit/id/12/key/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/

EXCEPTION:

> 1 exception(s):
>   Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $options of Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config.
>
> Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $options of Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config.
>
> #0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\Eav\Mod...', Array, Array)
>
> #1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Eav\Mod...', Array)
>
> #2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Validator/UniversalFactory.php(36): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Mod...', Array)
>
> #3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/AbstractAttribute.php(537): Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory->create('Magento\Eav\Mod...')
>
> #4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Customer/DataProvider.php(320): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute->getSource()
>
> #5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Customer/DataProvider.php(152): Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\DataProvider->getAttributesMeta(Object(Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Type))
>
> #6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93): Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\DataProvider->__construct('customer_form_d...', 'entity_id', 'id', Object(Magento\Ui\DataProvider\EavValidationRules), Object(Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory), Object(Magento\Eav\Model\Config), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool), Array, Array)
>
> #7 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(89): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\Custome...', Array)
>
> #8 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Custome...', Array)
>
> #9 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Argument/Interpreter/ConfigurableObject.php(60): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\Custome...', Array)
>
> #10 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Data/Argument/InterpreterInterface/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Argument\Interpreter\ConfigurableObject->evaluate(Array)
>
> #11 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Composite.php(61): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\InterpreterInterface\Proxy->evaluate(Array)
>
> #12 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(188): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate(Array)
>
> #13 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(192): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->evaluateComponentArguments(Array)
>
> #14 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(172): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->evaluateComponentArguments(Array)

This issue occur post migration and i have tried all cache process and deleted that many times so please provide some other good way to fix
In case any other information required let me know.

Comment: I have the same issue. cache clean or di:compile didn't help

Answer (score 2):

You can change your \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config
from

```
public function __construct(array $options)
```

to

```
public function __construct(array $options = null)
```

and make a breackpoint at line

```
$this->_optionsData = $options;
```

to catch the case when $options is not set. So you would find the corresponding attribute and fix it.

Refer this link :- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10141

This link solved my problem.